# How do I wrangle messy, raw data and import into R?

Tags: r, import, time-series, data-wrangling, raw-data

I have raw, messy data for time series containing around 1400 observations. Here is a snippet of what it looks like:

```
[new Date('2021-08-24'),1.67,1.68,0.9,null],[new Date('2021-08-23'),1.65,1.68,0.9,null],[new Date('2021-08-22'),1.62,1.68,0.9,null] ... etc
```

I want to pull the date and its respective value to form a tsibble in R. So, from the above values, it would be like

| Date | y-variable |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-24 | 1.67 |
| 2021-08-23 | 1.65 |
| 2021-08-22 | 1.62 |

Notice how only the first value is to be paired with its respective date - I don't need the other values. Right now, the raw data has been copied and pasted into a word document and I am unsure about how to approach data wrangling to import into R.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I assume the input does not contain linebreaks. Those were only added with the edit to the question. If they exist, the code from my answer can be adapted easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#replace the text conncetion with a file connection if desired, the file should be a txt then
input <- readLines(textConnection("[new Date('2021-08-24'),1.67,1.68,0.9,null],[new Date('2021-08-23'),1.65,1.68,0.9,null],[new Date('2021-08-22'),1.62,1.68,0.9,null]"))

#insert line breaks
input <- gsub("],[", "\n", input, fixed = TRUE)

#remove "new Date"
input <- gsub("new Date", "", input, fixed = TRUE)

#remove parentheses and brackets
input <- gsub("[\\(\\)\\[\\]]", "", input, perl = TRUE)

#import cleaned data
DF <- read.csv(text = input, header = FALSE, quote = "'")
DF$V1 <- as.Date(DF$V1)
print(DF)
#          V1   V2   V3  V4   V5
#1 2021-08-24 1.67 1.68 0.9 null
#2 2021-08-23 1.65 1.68 0.9 null
#3 2021-08-22 1.62 1.68 0.9 null
```

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
text <- "[new Date('2021-08-24'),1.67,1.68,0.9,null],[new Date('2021-08-23'),1.65,1.68,0.9,null],[new Date('2021-08-22'),1.62,1.68,0.9,null]"

df <- read.table(text = unlist(strsplit(gsub('new Date\\(|\\)', '', gsub('^.(.*).$', '\\1', text)), "].\\[")), sep = ",")

> df
          V1   V2   V3  V4   V5
1 2021-08-24 1.67 1.68 0.9 null
2 2021-08-23 1.65 1.68 0.9 null
3 2021-08-22 1.62 1.68 0.9 null
```

Changing column names and removing the last columns is trivial from this point